# How to migrate PFFile from existing Parse database to new one?

Tags: ios, database, parse-platform, database-migration

Unfortunately, we all know Parse is shutting down next year. However, it's great they open-sourced their code. I've read through the documentation and successfully set up my own local server. However, I'm unable to migrate PFFiles from my old Parse.com server to my new, locally hosted server.

I suspect in the coming months many of us will need this question answered, so a thorough, detailed answer will be well received. Thanks in advance.

Update 2-14-16:

For those still struggling to migrate their servers, check out this tutorial I found: https://learnappmaking.com/how-to-migrate-parse-app-parse-server-heroku-mongolab